# What is the sum of the series with general term $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\pi^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, fourier-series

Evaluate

$$\frac 1 {2\pi}\left(\frac{\pi^3}{3\times1!}-\frac{\pi^5}{5\times3!}+\frac{\pi^7}{7\times5!}-\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\times(2n-1)!}+\cdots\right)$$

I tried it by using the fact that $\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\pi^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ is a general term of the sine series, but I'm  not getting how to introduce the term $(2n+1)$ in the denominator term?

Comment: Did you try differentiation?

Comment: @Clayton:see the edit

Comment: I wonder how would the series representation of $\int x\sin x\, dx$ look like.

Comment: @user355705:i got it....

Comment: @zhw. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\Rightarrow\\ 
\int_0^\pi x\sin x\, dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^\pi x^{2k+2}\, dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+3}\Big|_0^\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{\pi^{2k+3}}{2k+3}.
$$

The computation of $\int_0^\pi x\sin x\, dx$ is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\pi^{2n - 1} \over \pars{2n - 1}!}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\bracks{\pars{2n - 1} - 1}/2}\,\pi^{2n - 1} 
 \over \pars{2n - 1}!} 
\\[5px] = &\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\pars{n - 1}/2}\,\pi^{n} 
 \over n!}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ic\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\pi\ic}^{n} \over n!} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\pi\ic}^{n} \over n!}} =
\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\pi\ic}^{n} \over n!} =
\Im\pars{\expo{\pi\ic} - 1}
\\[5mm] & = \sin\pars{\pi} = \bbx{0}
\end{align}